# Using grep -E with variables

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do a search with find and pass the results into grep. Grep has to find the files matched against string1 and string2 and string3.

I have the following command:

```
#/bin/bash
searchpath="/home/myfolder"
string1="abc"
string2="def"
string3="ghi"
find `echo "${searchpath}"` -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E '"${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"'
```

But the result is blank, but when I do:

`find /home/myfolder -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E 'abc.*def.*ghi'`

I get results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To debug this, just run `string1="abc" string2="def" string3="ghi" echo '"${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"'` to see what grep sees.

Comment: known fact, single quotes disable variable expansion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the line:

```
find `echo "${searchpath}"` -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E '"${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"'
```

i.e., saying:

```
find "${searchpath}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E "${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"
```

would work.  When you surround those with single quotes, the shell is interpreting it as:

```
"${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"
```

(without expanding the variables)

Moreover, you don't need to say

```
`echo "${searchpath}"`
```

Saying

```
"${searchpath}"
```

would suffice.

Comment: Note that it's better to put the entire search string in double-quotes (i.e. `"${string1}.*${string2}.*${string3}"` instead of `"${string1}".*"${string2}".*"${string3}"`) to keep the shell from treating the `*` as file matching wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use command substitution. And you should use `""` for quoting variables, not `'`:

```
find "${searchpath}" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E "${string1}.*${string2}.*${string3}"
```